# Autonomous AKKA actor calling receive actively

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, akka, actor

I want to implement advanced communication patterns with akka 2.1.
However, akka seems to differ from Scala's actors in a key aspect. Where scala's actors allow me to actively call "receive" and provide a partial function, akka's actors adopt the hollywood "don't call us, we'll call you" principle and let's you only define a receive function statically.

In scala's actors, I could have a pattern like this:

```
class MyActor extends Actor{

  override def act(){
    val x = expensiveFunc()
    friend ! x
    val y = receive {
      case Answer(a) => println(a)
    }
  }

}
```

Here, I explicitly make calls to receive. The reason for this is that I need autonomous actors that each perform a SPMD program and communicates at specific points in the execution.
Is it possible to emulate this pattern using AKKA in a meaningful way?

---

**EDIT** 
I guess it's fair to give complete insight into my problem.

I need to create a SPMD program using actors. This means I need to be able to define behaviour for the actors which is **not** only reactive i.e. I need to be able to implement **act()** like in the old scala actors.
Furthermore, I need to explicitly call **receive(p:PartialFunction[T,U])** like I could do in the old scala actors.

If I can do the above two things, I will be able to port my SPMD program from the old actors to akka actors. I suspect however that it is not possible to implement an act method due to the hollywood-pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle) that AKKA seems to adopt.

**EDIT2**
I believe the active receive problem might be solved with become/unbecome as something like this:

```
  import context._
  def receive(p:PartialFunction[Any,Unit]){
    become(p)
    receive()
    unbecome()
  }
```

However, this requires that nested calls to receive are allowed. There is a chance that I can emulate the **act** method by simply sending a message like:

```
case class Act(b: ()=> Unit) extends Serializable
```

Which then encapsulates the behaviour I would like my actor to perform.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to do this is to use [Future](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html)

Comment: Each actor is stateful, i.e. friend is a specific actor!

Comment: so, I will use ask for this pattern [Ask](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) : friend ? x will give you a Future and you can do Await.result for example to get result, or like future onsuccess { println(a) }

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. All actors do meaningful work and own different data. Friend is a specific actor and can be remote or local. There should be no master actor here.

Comment: not sure to clearly understand, but if you must change the "receive" of MyActor, you can use become/unbecome (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)

Comment: I think this will actually work with your suggestion and my own (edited the question)

Comment: Please not that become does not store the previous bahvior. You want to call become(newReceive, discardOld = false).

Comment: But I have the feeling that you go against the library here. Why do you want to explicitly call receive? Why can't you use a self message?

Also, you should not send around functions.

Comment: What do you mean by self message? The framework I am developing is very complex and strictly disregards master/slave patterns to achieve higher efficiency and scalability. Therefore, actors need to be stateful and perform a SPMD program in order to keep track of a global state. While this is by no means using the philosophy of AKKA, AKKA is a perfect backend to provide reliable message passing.

Comment: And about functions, I will only send one function to each local actor containing the SPMD body.

Comment: Have you solved this with the provided link in the answer? I have the same problem (ie explicitly calling `receive` in a research project) but as my mailbox is not Akka's default and is a custom priority mailbox, I cannot use Akka Stash. @Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some control over your mailbox using Stash:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/actors.html#Stash

Answer (score 0):

Akka actors are event-driven. Whenever a message is ready for consumption from the actors mailbox, the partial function defined in receive in the actor is called with the message passed in.

In other words, "receive" is not an imperative construct, you cannot call it to wait for the next message. What you want is achievable via normal message passing. The requester actor sends the data to the worker actor, which executes the expensive operation, and then sends back the reply.

Comment: I must avoid this approach to maximize performance. Sending the data to be processed imposes a big bottleneck on my system and produces master/slave like systems. This will not work for my program.